# How to create react fragment by createElement function

Tags: reactjs

```
const OnlyDesktop = ({ children, tag = 'div', className }: Props) => {
  return createElement(
    tag,
    { className: clsx(styles.root, className) },
    children
  );
};
```

Imagine I have a function above , where I want to make some wrapper , which will be by `css` show some content only for `desktop` width. And for cases where I wan't to wrapp it with some `div`, or `p` element , it is clear, but which `tag` should I pass to `createElement` function , to create `<></>` some `react.fragment` ?

Comment: Pass it '' and inside the component test with if

Comment: `React.createElement(React.Fragment, ..., ...)` (from https://babeljs.io/repl)

Answer (score 4):

To create a react fragment using `createElement`, Just do

```
React.createElement(React.Fragment);
```